# REST API - Returning a list of resources with different data

Tags: java, rest

I'm trying to figure what would be the best way of mapping a couple of use cases I have on my REST API.
I have 2 resources/entities: User and Organization

An Organization contains several users (one to many relationship).

I have 2 different use cases:

1. Retrieve a list of all Organizations without any Users (the User data isn't needed on this case)
2. Retrieve a list of all Organizations with all its associated Users

So I have the first one mapped to `GET /api/Organization`

What would be the generalized good way of mapping the second one in REST standards?
I need to get everything in one request, cannot be sending a new request to get the list of users for each Organization because performance wise would be terrible.

I thought about 3 different possibilities:

1) Something along these lines: `GET /api/Organization/customlist/with-users`

I really don't like this because it's not really REST standard and would get confused with sub-resources.

2) Use Query params for this: `GET /api/Organization?getusers=true`

This is cleaner, but I also don't like it much as I prefer to keep query params for filtering, paging and sorting purposes only.

3) Use a JSON object in the `GET` body and use `GET /api/Organization` for both use cases

Then depending on the content of the JSON object I would know if I should get the user list or not. I actually like this approach the best since it allows me to use the same path for both requests, but I'm aware that the general consensus seems to be that's a bad practice to use a body on GET requests even though lately this seems to have become a lot more common with some popular projects like ElasticSearch using this approach.

Is there a standardized way of dealing with similar cases? Any other way I might have missed? I can make it work with any of these of course, but I'm trying to understand what the best practices would be for something which I believe should be a common scenario.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be to define Organization to always return user data, to keep things simple and consistent.

Assuming there are specific reasons this isn't possible, one way you might approach this is to use specific [content types](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) for each of the cases, and allow the single end-point to support multiple types - so one type could be used to request to "light" Organization representation without user data, the other to request the "full" Organization specification with user data.

Clients can use [accept headers](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1) to specify which type of content they want, and many REST-implementing libraries support specifying handlers for a given content type

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: This post should have been comment instead of answer, but because of formatting/size issue, I am putting it in as answer.

Go with option 2. You don't have to maintain query parameters for later use, once you have implemented the model properly seeing the query param. I will also recommend that don't use QP like : `getusers=true` but use a generic qp, like `?includeChild=users; or ?expand=users`.

Using this way, you are future proof with more childs/multi level of master details relationship e.g if tomorrow you may have a need for address under users, then you can do `?show(or includeChild)=users,address` and so on. You can also include a generic expand value `?show=all` to include all childs.

Also I assume when you are "not" including the "users" in organization, you are any way giving the links of "users" in response for users/clients to auto drill down. Something like : (pseudo structure)

```
{
 Organizations:
 {
  Org1:
  {
     details..
     org1.self link (e.g if anyone just want to fetch one item of organizations) like /organizations/1
     org1.child1.link  i,e /organizations/1/users

  }
 }
}
```

by giving just the child link in the organizations details, for default use, you can give a link to users to fetch the child information.

That is how it goes in a better rest design. I assume.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the generalized good way of mapping the second one in REST standards?

REST doesn't care how you spell your URI.
REST doesn't care how many URI you use.
REST doesn't care how many different URI you use to represent the "same" entities in your domain model.

Remember, in the REST architectural style, most URI are discovered (rather than bookmarked/permalinked).

But (virtually) nobody does it that way.  So we press on....

*Cool URI don't change* -- you want to be careful about coupling your REST endpoints too tightly to your domain model, because that increases the cost of modifying the model.  You should be able to improve your domain implementation without necessarily changing your API.

So I would recommend that you reserve part of your URI namespace for resources that modify the entities in your domain, and do your fancy reporting in a separate part of your namespace

```
/model/organization/{organizationid}

vs

/reports/activeOrganizationsDigest?asOf=2016-05-27
/reports/activeOrganizations/showUsers?activeSince=2015-12-12
```

URI are *cheap*; don't feel like you need to be stingy with them.

```
/userStories?asA=marketingStrategist&iWantTo=reviewCurrentOrganizations&soThat=iCanPlanNewCampaigns
/userStories?asA=emailScammer&iWantTo?mineEmailAddresses&soThat=iCanBroadcastMoreSpam
```

> Ceci n'est pas une pipe

A part of the success of the web that Fielding was documenting was that decoupling the identifier from the representation provided flexibility that allowed the web to become more than just a static document transfer application.

> The song's name is called Haddocks' Eyes...
>
> The song's name is The Aged Aged Man...
>
> The song is called Ways and Means...
>
> The song is A-sitting on a Gate...

[Charles Lutwidge Dodgson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Carroll) on the power of [decoupling the name from the entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haddocks%27_Eyes).